# Can't run application after use Clickone publish

Tags: c, winforms, devexpress

I have a winform project, using Devexpress 18.2
I was use Clickone publish to deploy my project, and when i run application file, i had a error like
***Strong name signature not valid for this assembly DevExpress.Data.v18.2.dll.***
How can i fix it?
tks u all!

Comment: Hi @Lê Trung Hiếu, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post additional information like config files, package.json/csproj or other additional things that  you think would help others understand this issue better?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Devexpress?

Comment: i did. But it still not work

Comment: @raghav710 in my project Reference, include DevExpress.Data.v18.2. and when i publish my project Applications Files include it too, but after publish, i can't run application file because of this error : Strong name signature not valid for this assembly DevExpress.Data.v18.2.dll.

Comment: @LêTrungHiếu were you able to solve this? sorry for the delay. I am not that sure about ClickOne publish but I think you might have to somehow skip checking strong naming for the assembly. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922861/2102114